# oAuth2 - There is no request token for this page error

Tags: oauth-2.0, token, twitter-oauth

I'm new to oAuth2 and trying to adapt this [ActionScript3 oAuth2 library](http://blogs.adobe.com/charles/2012/05/oauth-2-0-library-for-actionscript.html) example to authorize a Twitter application instead of Google.

```
// From the example:
var oauth2:OAuth2 = new OAuth2("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", LogSetupLevel.ALL);

var grant:IGrantType = new AuthorizationCodeGrant(stageWebView, "INSERT_CLIENT_ID_HERE", "INSERT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE", "http://www.example.com", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
```

My try:

```
var oauth2:OAuth2 = new OAuth2("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", LogSetupLevel.ALL);

var grant:IGrantType = new ImplicitGrant(stageWebView, "Consumer-Key", "Consumer-Secret", "http://www.example.com", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
```

I'm running into this error:

> "There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we
>   need from applications asking to use your Twitter account"

Why is there no request token found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my knowledge twitter is using OAuth1.0A not OAuth2.0